# Site quality in questions and answers solution

Tags: discussion

Lately I have seen and talked to people about the level of quality and ideas how we can improve it.  Since a majority of people suggest another addition of a closed reason I am partially against it based on the user being new and unfamiliar with our format.  Per some discussion in the chat it was brought up we could automate our comment system ([AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)).  So instead of a closed apocalypse I thought we could come up with a way to address quality questions and answers with a default comment in the hopes it will encourage the user to make an edit.  What questions and answers do you suggest we should have a default comment for?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the pre-fabricated comments section, I think we should expand our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) to include suggestions on how to write decent quality questions for common problems. An example of something to add would be:

> **Q: How can I write a good question to achieve a certain effect?**
>
> ---
>
> **A:** Please, for the love of pixels, show us what you have tried!

We can only write so much within a comment, so the idea here is to provide a rich resource for users to visit that is longer than 600 characters

Comment: While I agree in providing a rich resource sometimes the amount of material can be a deterant

Comment: We can link to meta posts from the faq, right? We can vote on the comments or create a wiki-style post and use that instead of charging the faq too much.

Comment: I think a wiki style post would be good.